# c# - Compare distinct classes on containing the same set of variables/properties

Tags: c#, class, comparison

I got currently stuck trying to create a class-updater.

There is a serializable **ClassA** that contains an *Integer*-, and a *String*-variable for example. **ClassA** is cast to *object*, serialized and then saved to a Binary-File. 
Afterwards there is a program update which alters **ClassA** to contain two *Integer*- and the *String*-variable. The old **ClassA** is renamed to **ClassA_0**. 
When the data is being loaded back from the Binary-File, the deserialized *object* is passed as an argument to an updater method.

The problem is:  How do I compare that *object* to **ClassA_0** and **ClassA** to dertermine the "version" it was being saved as?

Edit:

```
[Serializable]
public class ClassA
{
    int VarA;
    int VarB;
    string VarC;


    public ClassA()
    {
        //[...]
    }

    public void MethodX()
    {
        //[...]
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ClassA_0
{
    int VarA;
    string VarB;


    public ClassA()
    {
        //[...]
    }

    public void MethodX()
    {
        //[...]
    }
}
```

These are dummy classes, so i didn't specify any code in the constructor or methods.

Comment: You don't, you have to know the type to deserialize into on beforehand. So you can't deserialize into, say, `object` and then try and figure out what type it actually is.

Comment: Can you post the class structure for ClassA and ClassA_O

Comment: "serialized" - serialized how? is this `BinaryFormatter`? if so... I just wouldn't - do you have any flexibility to change your serialization approach?

Comment: @Alex added the structure

Comment: @MarcGravell it is currently serialized by the BinaryFormatter, since it is still in dev. I'm open for other approaches aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was me, I would look at a tool like protobuf-net (bias: I'm the author, but: all free etc) which gives you more control over these things. I would then do something like:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ClassA
{
    [ProtoMember(1)
    int Version { get { return 1; } set {} }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    int VarA;
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    int VarB;
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    string VarC;


    public ClassA()
    {
        //[...]
    }

    public void MethodX()
    {
        //[...]
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassA_0
{
    [ProtoMember(1)
    int Version { get { return 2; } set {} }

    [ProtoMember(2)] // this is the same - compatible, keep tag
    int VarA;
    [ProtoMember(5)] // not the same: new tag
    string VarB;


    public ClassA()
    {
        //[...]
    }

    public void MethodX()
    {
        //[...]
    }
}
```

Note that there's a dummy property in tag `1` which only has a `get` and ignores values - this ensures that we serialize a version with the data for later lookup (since you want that). We *could* also add a `set` that throws an error about the version, but I'd prefer to make it as compatible as possible.

`VarA` is present and compatible in both - we can use tag 2 for that. The other data is incompatible, so a new and different tag is used (5); now we can use `Serializer.Deserialize<ClassA>(...)`, or the `Serializer.NonGeneric` equivalent if you prefer, and the data should deserialize. But we might also want to just check the version - we can do that:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class VersionInfo {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Version {get;set;}
}
```

now we can just use `Serializer.Deserialize<VersionInfo>` **on the same data**, and it will just deserialize the version tag and discard everything else. Once we know the version, we can branch, etc. This could *also* be done by some form of inheritance, but it seems overkill here.

Comment: This could actually help big-time. I'll try it later today, and come back here after that.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

The specification for the BinaryFormatter binary stream is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844.aspx). You could read the stream directly (not using the deserializer) and figure out the Type from that